# Selected text from window is coming as empty

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

i am trying to wrap the selected string between two characters
for eg: selecting 'test' and clicking on change button will change the selected text to 'atestb'
the problem is that, i am able to replace the selected text, but window.getSelection().toString() is coming empty. 
This is the function that im using

```
  replaceSelectedText(startTag, endTag) {
    let sel, range;
    console.log(window.getSelection().toString())
    if (window.getSelection) {
      sel = window.getSelection();
      if (sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();
        const selectedContent = sel.toString();
        console.log("Selected Content ")
        console.log(selectedContent)
        let replaceDiv = startTag + selectedContent;
        replaceDiv=endTag ? replaceDiv + endTag : replaceDiv;
        range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(replaceDiv));
      }
    } else if ((document as any).selection && (document as any).selection.createRange) {
      range = (document as any).selection.createRange();
      range.text = startTag;
    }
  }
```

Link to Stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-idyhj5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deleting the value before retrieving it.

```
range.deleteContents();
const selectedContent = sel.toString();
```

If you flip those two lines and store the contents before deleting, it will work as you expect.